# This is being to + infinitive (the reason)

Tags: sentence-construction

Original sentence.

> a) The reason *being that* you will be free from extra shipping for the transfer.

Can we reconstruct the sentence as,

> b) This *is being to* make you free from extra shipping for the transfer.

Comment: This is **to exempt** (free) you from extra shipping charges...

Comment: @ Mari-lou A... Thanks ... but my question is about using "This is being to" is correct or not.

Comment: It wasn't as an answer but a possible alternative

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested re-write of the sentence, unfortunately, is not grammatical.

Maybe part of the problem in your understanding of the original is that your quotation does not seem complete.

When we say "*the reason being that...*" it normally *follows* a statement and is linking that statement it to the reason why, for example:

> I went to bed early, the reason being that I was tired from the previous day.

Your sentence contains a reason but does not say what it is a reason for.

You could rewrite my example as:

> The reason I went to be early was that I was tired from the previous day.

or simply:

> I went to bed early *because* I was tired from the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is about using "This is being to" is correct or not

Well, in your example b), it is not really correct. I would say it like:

> b) This is **done** to make you free from extra shipping for the transfer.

However, **Mari-LouA**'s comment makes a lot of sense (as in: it fits the context and the specific terminology much better):

> This is to **exempt** (free) you from extra shipping charges...